# XSL: Matching ID on a multiple attribute tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0

I been working at this for a while, but couldn't come to any type of working solution. All this is in xml version 1.

The first file called dog_info.xml has something of this sort:

```
<?xml version"1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dog_info version="2" dog_num="2" update_time="2013-15-05T14:80:00Z">
   <dog_list xml: lang="en">
      <dog id="1" name="Nikki" desc="Black with brown spots"/>
      <dog id="2" name="Zulu" desc="Oreo color"/>
      <dog id="3" name="Tyler" desc="brown dog"/>
      <dog id="4" name="Sally" desc="milk color"/>
      <dog id="5" name="Joe" desc="brown and grey color"/>
   </dog_list>
   <dog_list xml:lang="piggylatin">
      <dog id="1" name="Nikky" desc="black spots with black and brown spots"/>
      <dog id="2" name="apples" desc="green, red or blue apples"/>
      <dog id="3" name="Taylor" desc="yellow dog"/>
      <dog id="4" name="Susan" desc="a dog"/>
      <dog id="5" name="Jason" desc="a cat"/>
   </dog_list>
</dog_info>
```

The second file called profile.xml has something of this sort:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<profile>
   <animal-helper>
      <animal>
         <category>
            <rule>
               <value>1</value>
               <deny />
            </rule>
            <rule>
               <value>2</value>
               <deny />
            </rule>
         </category>
      </animal>
   </animal-helper>
</profile>
```

The 3rd file is what I am writing, but am stuck. It should be an xsl that I can parse into a html to display the information.

profile.xml has a value 1 and deny. If it is deny, it will be matched with the id in dog_list.xml and retrieve the name and desc. Same with any other deny.

There is no `<allow />` tags, but just `<deny />`. So All the rest of the id in dog_list.xml are allowed. and should be listed in it's own category on the html.

I also have to pay attention to see if the language isn't "piggylatin" or "en" it will default to "en". Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit:

The actual file is very large, and used for work. So I had to recreate something that was similar to what I need to get it working.

I have something like:

```
...


<xsl:for-each select="$HELPER/animal/category/rule[name=false()]">
   <xsl:variable name="currentValue" select="value/text()"/>
   <xsl:variable name="dogValue" select="$DOG_LIST"/> 
   <xsl:for-each select="$dogValue/dog[@id = $currentValue]">
      <xsl:apply-templates/><xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<br />]]></xsl:text></xsl:if>
   </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
...
```

Edit 2:

The snippet of the code above is part of a html table (deny section). It should look something like this:

**"Deny"**
Nikki
Zulu

**"Allowed"** 
Tyler
Sally
Joe

So the "Deny" finds value 1 and 2, matches with id 1 and 2, and returns the names.
And the "Allowed" finds id 3, 4, 5, (since 1 and 2) are denied and returns the names.

The purpose of the `<deny />` element is to pick out the denied dogs and list them, and then based on that, the other "id" that weren't denied would be allowed.

The above part of the code I wrote would have two parts. The "Deny" part and the "Allowed" part. The Allowed part would have to be testing for the other "id"s that weren't selected initially for `<deny />`.

Comment: Can you show us what XSLT you have so far? And I don't see any mention of languages in your second XML file. How is one supposed to "see if the language isn't 'piggylatin'"?

Comment: I added the part that I was working on above. This was one of the test statements was similar to what I needed. I guess it came down to, how would you be able to match an value to another id and grab information  when the tag had multiple attributes. The whole "piggylatin" was just something that I had to pay attention to, I think that part of localization would be more clear once I have this part worked out.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I still don't understand the purpose of the `<deny />` element and what you want it to do. Can you show us what the desired output would be, given those two files?

Comment: Hi, I updated it again. Showing what the outcome should be (relatively), and hopefully explained it better this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over the **rule** elements, you could reverse the logic and loop over the **dog** elements in the first file, firstly picking the only that have a corresponding **deny**, and then again to pick those that don't.

To create a look of for the **rule** elements, you can define a variable, like so

```
<xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('profile.xml')/profile/animal-helper/animal/category/rule" />
```

To look up **dog** elements which are denied, you can then just do this (assuming you are positioned on the **dog_info** element in the first file)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="dog[@id=$lookup[deny]/value]" />
```

And to get the non-deny ones, just do this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="dog[not(@id=$lookup[deny]/value)]" />
```

In terms of the 'language', well, you could just start off by selecting the **dog_info** element with the required language

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="dog_list[@xml:lang='en']" />
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:variable name="lookup" select="document('profile.xml')/profile/animal-helper/animal/category/rule" />

   <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="dog_list[@xml:lang='en']" />
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="dog_list">
      DENY:<br />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="dog[@id=$lookup[deny]/value]" />
      APPROVE:<br />
         <xsl:apply-templates select="dog[not(@id=$lookup[deny]/value)]" />
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="dog">
         <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
         <br />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This should output the following

```
  DENY:<br>
  Nikki<br>
  Zulu<br>
  APPROVE:<br>
  Tyler<br>
  Sally<br>
  Joe<br>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all: Forget that `<xsl:for-each>` exists. It makes easy things difficult. And you (almost) never need it.

Write templates and use template matching, concentrate on *selecting nodes* and *applying templates to them*, instead of writing nested loops.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:variable name="profile" select="document('profile.xml')" />
  <xsl:variable name="denied" select="$profile//animal/category/rule[deny]/value" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html>
      <head><!-- ... --></head>
      <body>
        <h1>Denied</h1>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dog_list/dog[@id = $denied]" />
        </ul>

        <h1>Allowed</h1>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="dog_list/dog[not(@id = $denied)]" />
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dog">
    <li><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Regarding language and default language, work with parameters and a key:

```
<xsl:param name="defaultLang" select="'en'" />
<xsl:param name="displayLang" select="'piggylatin'" />

<!-- index dogs by their language and ID -->
<xsl:key name="kDogByLang" match="dog" select="concat(../@xml:lang, '/', @id)" />


<!-- ...and replace the dog template with this: -->

<xsl:template match="dog">
  <xsl:variable name="default" select="key('kDogByLang', concat($defaultLang, '/', @id))" />
  <xsl:variable name="display" select="key('kDogByLang', concat($displayLang, '/', @id))" />

  <xsl:choose>
    <!-- if this is the correct language, output it -->
    <xsl:when test="generate-id() = generate-id($display)">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="$display/@name" /></li>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- if this is the default lang (and no correct lang exists), output this -->
    <xsl:when test="generate-id() = generate-id($default) and not($display)">
      <li><xsl:value-of select="$default/@name" /></li>
    </xsl:when>

    <!-- there is no "otherwise" - all other cases shall not produce output -->
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

This way you can easily configure your stylesheet's output by passing in the correct parameter values.

Sample: http://www.xmlplayground.com/jv3TvQ